# Why don't we create an Event Handler delegate for binding a handler with an event when programmatically creating an event handler?

Tags: c#, event-handling, delegates, eventhandler

I am creating a Windows Form application in Visual Studio using C#. I am having trouble understanding the concept of Event Handler Delegates.

If I create an event handler for an event using the Properties window, Visual Studio auto generates this code in the Designer file:
`this.btnLogin.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnLogin_Click);`
However, if I programmatically create the event handler, I don't have to create an Event Handler delegate.
`btnLogin.Click += btnLogin_Click;`
Why is that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# delegate: literal constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30831469/c-sharp-delegate-literal-constructor)

Comment: @Charlieface you literally linked a question that is duplicate of duplicate of duplicate.

Comment: @GrandSirr If I was gold badge I would have linked all of them. This way a gold-badger can link them all.

Comment: A delegate is a reference type. In terms of data structure, a delegate is a user-defined type just like a class. When the delegate is called, all methods contained in the delegate will be executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, if I programmatically create the event handler, I don't have to create an Event Handler delegate.

This is where you're mistaken. You *are* creating an `EventHandler` instance, you're just doing it via a [*method group conversion*](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/conversions.md#108-method-group-conversions) instead of a [*delegate creation expression*](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/expressions.md#117156-delegate-creation-expressions). It's just different syntax for the same thing.

Note that there's nothing special about `EventHandler` here. Here's an example of the same thing with `Action` (which is about the simplest delegate there is):

```cs
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Delegate creation expression
        Action action1 = new Action(MyMethod);
        // Method group conversion
        Action action2 = MyMethod;
    }

    static void MyMethod() {}
}
```